# Python Pandas Scraping Multiple Webpages to Multiple Data Frames?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, web-scraping

Noob here. I am trying to organize traits per token number, luckily this webpage has them listed starting from /0.
https://ape.offbase.org/token/0

I cant seem to get them into a usable dictionary to work with. I need to be able to lookup the token number and reference its traits. Tokens also have different trait counts. This is what I have so far:

```
URL = 'https://ape.offbase.org/token/'


for page in range(0,10):


req = requests.get(URL + str(page) + '/')
dfs = pd.read_html(URL + str(page) + '/')
df = dfs[0:10]
print(df)
```

Results:

```
[            0            1
0  Background       Orange
1     Clothes  Striped Tee
2     Earring  Silver Hoop
3        Eyes       X Eyes
4         Fur        Robot
5       Mouth   Discomfort]
```

Comment: use a dictionary with key as page number, value as a data frame. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining a *dictionary*.

Where each key will be the loop iterator and the value will be a DataFrame, as suggested in the comment

```
URL = 'https://ape.offbase.org/token/'

results = {}
for page in range(0,10):

    req = requests.get(URL + str(page) + '/')
    value = pd.read_html(URL + str(page) + '/')[0]
    
    results[page] = value
```

would work as a pseudo-list

```
result[0]
```

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Background | Orange |
| Clothes | Striped Tee |
| Earring | Silver Hoop |
| Eyes | X Eyes |
| Fur | Robot |
| Mouth | Discomfort |

Comment: Thank you for this! Do you know any way to make results into a complete dataframe so I can export the entire thing to csv?